# Dynamic List in Model for MVC3 Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, entity-framework

I'm building a driver's application for employment and I'd like the list of 'accidents' to be dynamic in the sense of only one field appears, but they can add however many they need and once added they appear in a table above the input..

I'm trying to find out what the best way to do this is in a MVC3 Form that is using Razor syntax?

Model has a declaration similar to...

```
public class FormModel {
...other properties
public IEnumerable<AccidentDetail> AccidentDetails { get; set; }
...other properties
}
```

This is very much shortened, but wanted to ensure that I was declaring it properly in the model and then I need to know how it's generally handled in the Form to do something like this.  I can't make any assumptions to the existence of an accident or the limit of how many they may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would approach this with some JavaScript.  In particular, I'd use jQuery to add a new field to the table when a button is clicked to "Add another accident".  You can use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) to grab the values of the fields into an array. The array of accidents would be serialized to json and stored in a hidden field on the form that would be submitted to the server.  In your controller you could deserialize that string of json to your strong type.  On the server side I've used [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) with great success.  On the client side you can use [Doug Crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).  Feel free to email me if you need a little bigger push in the right direction.

Comment: MVC has a JsonResult return type for controller actions, use that over Json.NET.

Comment: I'm not sure I could use that to get the valus from the client side to the server side though.

Comment: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/07/JsonValueProviderFactoryASPNETMVC3.aspx  you can.